# Cannot input wacom settings to map buttons using the gnome settings menu

Tags: gnome, wacom

The rest of the Wacom settings in ubuntu 22.04 works perfectly fine it's just when I'm mapping the Wacom buttons is the issue. When I press the map button menu all of the buttons are automatically not mapped or "application-defined", trying to change it so an assigned keystroke does nothing. I cant change any of the buttons from "application-defined". Idk if this sounds ramble-y.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be this bug if you are running GNOME 42: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/-/issues/1822